# Custom sound for Push Notification

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to receive push notifications in my app when sending from the Firebase Messaging console.

However, I want an mp3 that is in my app's bundle to play instead of the default sound.

Here's how I send the message:
[image]

But when I inspect the notification, the value of userInfo["aps"]["sound"] is 'default'. And so it plays the default sound.

The value of userInfo["sound"] is set to my filename, which isn't of help because this is outside of userInfo["aps"].

How do I get the value of userInfo["aps"]["sound"] to be my custom file name? Instead of default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can't set a custom value for userInfo["aps"]["sound"] via the Firebase console. So for testing, you'll have to send the push differently.

Instead, you can use the [Easy APNs Provider](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-apns-provider-push-notification/id989622350?mt=12) mac app. You supply this with an APS Push Cert that you've previously generated, as well as your device's token (as puctured):

[image]

You can obtain the token after approving push services from the app:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    print(deviceTokenString)
}
```

Now, my custom sound plays because the push's payload is properly structured. It would be nice if Firebase was able to resolve this from their console; in the meantime, I will use this method.

Comment: i am getting notifications from fcm . now , i want to make functionality such as when i will get notification from fcm , app should play a sound file without even touching notification message . do you know how to do that ? didRecieveRemoteNotification will only get executed when user tap on notification . i want to play a sound file like alarm tune when i get the notification . please guide me through it .